# How to change orientation of custom view layout by code?

Tags: android

I've created a custom view with the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
    android:paddingVertical="5dp"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <include
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/layout_field_label"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/valueTextView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textColor="@color/colorValue"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:text="@string/simpleValueViewer_text"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

the included layout is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ex_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/simpleValueEditor_label" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/infoIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_info_icon_16dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I use the custom view in a fragment this way:

```
<ivanapp.SimpleValueViewer
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:label="Цена"/>
```

And the result in UI is this:
[image]
i.e. when I use it with the default horizontal orientation it's what I want.

But I want to extend the custom view to able to configure it's orientation:
when it's vertical then the 'text' part should be under the 'label' part.
So I put the following method in the class and call this method from the constructor:

```
protected void initEx(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_simple_value_viewer, this, 
  true);
        mValueTextView = findViewById(R.id.valueTextView);
        TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, 
  R.styleable.SimpleValues);
        mLabel.setText(attributes.getString(R.styleable.SimpleValues_android_label));
        mValueTextView.setText(attributes.getString(R.styleable.SimpleValues_value));
        LinearLayout labelEx = findViewById(R.id.ex_label);
        switch(getOrientation()) {
            case LinearLayout.VERTICAL: {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams labelParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0
                );
                labelEx.setLayoutParams(labelParams);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams valueParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0
                );
                mValueTextView.setLayoutParams(valueParams);
                mValueTextView.setTop(labelEx.getHeight());
                setWeightSum(0);
                break;
            }
            case LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL: {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams labelParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 2
                );
                labelEx.setLayoutParams(labelParams);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams valueParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1
                );
                mValueTextView.setLayoutParams(valueParams);
                setWeightSum(labelParams.weight + valueParams.weight);
                break;
            }
        }
        attributes.recycle();
}
```

But when I try to use it with vertical orientation like this:

```
<ivanapp.SimpleValueViewer
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:label="Цена"/>
```

the effect in the UI is this:
[image]
i.e the 'text' part is not there.
I've done a lot of debugging but I'm stuck.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact it was easier than Ithough:

1)  I just created 2 layout files - one for horizontal and one for vertical.

2) I just load the file I neef.

and that's all :)